# Django and Jquery Autocomplete Issues

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I know there are several posts regarding autocomplete and django, but I'm recently entering in to the realm of jquery and somehow I'm lost. As you can imagine, I need an autocomplete for the following field:

HTML file

```
<div class="ui-widget">
     <input name="user_name"class="form-control "id="company-search">
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#company-search").autocomplete({
                    source: '{% url 'autocomplete' %}',
                    minLength: 1,
                });
            });
    </script>
```

URL

```
path('autocomplete/',views.autocomplete, name='autocomplete')
```

Views

```
def autocomplete(request):
    data  = request.GET['term']
    forecast = LeadEntry.objects.select_related('lead_id')
    companies = [str(i.lead_id.company).lower() for i in forecast]
    search = [i for i in companies if i.startswith(data.lower()) ]

    result = []
    for company in search:
        data = {}
        data['label'] = company
        data['value'] = company
        result.append(data)
    print(json.dumps(result))
    mimeetype='application/json'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result),mimeetype)
```

Please note that the ajax portion works well, I can see the view working every time, I type a new letter, I'm getting a json file with the correct data.

I can actually see the results, but the actual value is on the top right corner

[image]

I'm getting the following errors on the javascript side:

[image]

Regards

Comment: I think your problem is with the jQuery UI version, use the CDN version 1.13.0 jQuery UI  to see if it works?
`<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>`

Comment: Thanks, you should have added an answer, that solves the issue, I knew it had to be like that as the logic is simple, and the autocomplete is working, but the placement is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the comments section seems to have solved the problem, to help others I write here:

Problem is with the jQuery UI version, use the CDN version 1.13.0 jQuery UI:

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery [docs](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) the source property of autocomplete expects a list of keywords but you are passing it a django url.

You need to first hit your django url
most probably with ajax GET call to get list of keywords and then put that list of keywords in the autocomplete source property.